# Loading database values into a array

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, arrays

So I got a application all set up, multiple commands work splendid but I'm stuck on one major issue. I want to load values - data for SQL connection strings (serveradress/databasename/UID/password) from a SQL table. The connection to it works and I can retrieve data. What I want to achieve is that there are arrays for serveradress/databasename/UID/password (4 arrays total) where it loads the data into. There's also a name and DatabaseID in the SQL. So I can have the INT DatabaseID and use the select query to select a row where the databaseID is 5 and then get the info from that array. I can already save those to string variables but I want it to load all information to arrays when I start the application so that the connection can be closed. And databaseID then equals the number I use to select the Array data.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck. You haven't asked a specific question, you have just posted your requirements.

Comment: Tried nothing I can't think of a way to do what I want. The specific question is. How do I load values from a database into a array in c# so that I can select the values into the array using the DatabaseID/DatabaseName

Comment: why you want it in array. just use datatable and fetch accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using multiple arrays, I'd suggest your store your data in a list of objects. For example, you could define a class for your connection information as follows:

```
public class ConnInfo
{
    public string ServerAddress { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can hold a list of these:

```
var connections = new List<ConnInfo>();
```

And populate it from your database query:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    connections.Add(new ConnInfo 
    { 
        ServerAddress = (string)row["ServerAddress"],
        DatabaseName = (string)row["DatabaseName"],
        // etc.
    });
}
```

Once this is done, you can access your connection information as follows:

```
var address = connections[2].ServerAddress;
```

If you're not sure how to create the 'table' I refer to above, something like:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ConnectionInfo", myConnection);
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var table = new DataTable();
table.Load(rdr);
rdr.Close();
```

If you don't want to create a class for this, you could simply hold onto this DataTable, and use it directly to access the information.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked and does what I needed it to do! I'm still pretty fresh to C# and this is the first time I'm using SQL with it, so I thought a array would be the best option.

Answer (score -1):

I am a bit lost in what you are trying to achieve.

Why do you have 4 arrays? You can just return the information from your SQL table and store it ot a DataTable so you have all that information in one central table that you can query using LINQ as opposed  to loading the info into different arrays.

I hope this sheds some light.

Exactly like Alan explained and demonstrated.